# Data Tables. fix first column so not sort-able

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a data table. The first column is the position and is a increments so example has 1, 2, 3, 4. Showing the position a row is in. The rest of the columns i want sort-able. So when sorted by number of jobs, or total value the first column stays the same but the rest change.

I have tried using fixed column but this is not that i want.

```
<table class="datatable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Position</th>
                                <th class="no-sort">Name</th>
                                <th class="no-sort">Jobs</th>                                  
                                <th class="no-sort">Labour</th>
                                <th class="no-sort">Total</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        @{int count = 1;}
                        @foreach (Model make in Model.Models)
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>@(count)</td>
                                <td>@make.Name</td>
                                <td>@make.Jobs</td>
                                <td>@Math.Round(make.Labour, 2)</td>
                                 <td>@Math.Round(make.Total, 2)</td>
                            </tr>
                            { count++; }
                        }
                    </table>


  var Table = $('.datatable').dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "bFilter": false, "bInfo": false,
        "aaSorting": [[2, 'desc']],
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": 'no-sort',
            "orderable": false,
        } ],
        "aoColumns": [
            { "bSearchable": false },
            { "bSearchable": false },
            { "bSearchable": false },
       { "bSearchable": false },
          { "bSearchable": false },
            { "bSearchable": false }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: so you need to change first column or not

Comment: No i want the first column to be permanently fixed. All the other columns to be sortable

Comment: add targets:[0] and try it

Comment: sorry where do i add

Comment: So if you sort on any column other than the first the numbers in the first column go 1, 2, 3... N. And they always show 1, 2, 3... N no matter what?

Comment: yes thats what im trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this functionality by adding `Counter Column` that contains the position in the table for each row. You need to add it dynamically whenever `searching` and `ordering` operations are performed at DataTable.

```
oTable.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
        oTable.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
            cell.innerHTML = i+1;
        } );
    } ).draw();
```

Please see this [Example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html) for demonstration.

<kbd>[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/sy1p7ucw/)</kbd>

Comment: I am glad I am able to helped you. Welcome bro. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in your datatable code:

```
 "columnDefs": [
    { "orderable": false, "targets": 0 }
 ]
```